# 2 ways for submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms, submit

AFAIK there are 2 ways for submitting a form.

For example : asp.net has the [Button.UseSubmitBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) property which

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Button control uses the
>   **client browser's** submit mechanism or the **ASP.NET** postback mechanism.

If the value is set to `false` it generates the script below to submit the form.

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

**Question :**

However ,If it uses the *ASP.NET postback mechanism* - how is it done ?

- What is the **difference** between those 2 approaches of submitting a form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method without using postback is done with the browser's submit mechanism. Imagine a standard HTML form on a page with action and method attributes. Something like this:

```
<form action="server_script.asp" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then the postback method works as follows. From Microsoft's documentation:

> If you specify false, the ASP.NET page framework adds client-side script to the page to post the form to the server.

This mechanism overrides the browsers submit mechanism with a script (likely js) which submits the form. I have never used ASP.NET but I imagine it'll generate some AJAX code for you which submits the form to the server. There is an advantage to this in that the browser doesn't redirect to anywhere to submit the form. The browser stays on one page and the script silently submits the data to the server.

Comment: Your answer repeats my question facts. and the script for `__doPostBack` is not for ajax. ajax uses xmlhttp object. however it does used when updatepanel is in use. anyway , thats not my question.